# Theano fails to use GPU when running Python as module (python -m)

Tags: python, theano

I built a Python package so that I can do relative imports like:

```
from ..utils import gen_utils
```

from

```
package_name/gpu_code/script_using_theano.py
```

if my file structure is something like:

```
package_name/
--utils/
----gen_utils.py
--gpu_code/
----script_using_theano.py
```

However, when I run `python -m package_name.gpu_code.script_using_theano` I get the following error:

```
ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu: libcublas.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu is not available  (error: cuda unavilable)
```

This error does not appear when I just run

`python package_name/gpu_code/script_using_theano.py`

and I'm able to use the GPU just fine in that case. I'm wondering if there's some Theano config setting that's begin altered by running python as a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you import the files from outside the directory of the top file? If you aren’t using

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, './path/to/some/place/with/files/for/importing1')
sys.path.insert(0, './path/to/some/place/with/files/for/importing2')
import thing1
import thing2
```

I recommend that you do so.

Comment: Everything is imported relatively? I'm not sure what you mean. Anyways the problem is not with being able to import anything, it's just theano accessing the GPU when Python is run as a module.

Comment: Ah okay I see what you mean. Theano needs to import a path relative to my home directory in order to see its configuration file. Since I'm running as a module, the home directory was no longer in Python's path so I needed to explicitly add it. That worked